# properly logging unicode & utf-8 exceptions in python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, unicode, utf-8

I'm trying to log various exceptions from libraries in python 2.7. I find that sometimes the exceptions contain a unicode string and sometimes a utf8 bytestring. I thought that `logging.exception(e)` was the right approach to log them, but the following doesn't seem to work:

```
# encoding: utf-8
import logging
try:
    raise Exception('jörn')
except Exception as e:
    logging.exception(e)

try:
    raise Exception(u'jörn')
except Exception as e:
    logging.exception(e)
```

saving this into a file and running it results in this:

```
$ python test.py
ERROR:root:jörn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    raise Exception('jörn')
Exception: jörn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 859, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 732, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 474, in format
    s = self._fmt % record.__dict__
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf6' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file test.py, line 12
```

So as you see the utf8 exception worked fine, but the unicode exception broke logging, swallowing the real exception and hiding it behind a `UnicodeEncodeError`.

Is there some standard logging facility for exceptions that won't break my code? What am i missing?

Answer (score 4):

Actually, i think i finally found the mistake and a proper way myself: I seem to have used [`logging.exception('msg')`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.exception) wrong the whole time. You're not meant to pass in the exception, but a message:

```
# encoding: utf-8
import logging
try:
    raise Exception('jörn')
except Exception as e:
    logging.exception('exception occurred')

try:
    raise Exception(u'jörn')
except Exception as e:
    logging.exception('exception occurred')
```

running the above correctly logs the exception:

```
$ python test.py
ERROR:root:exception occurred
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    raise Exception('jörn')
Exception: jörn
ERROR:root:exception occurred
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
    raise Exception(u'jörn')
Exception: j\xf6rn
```

The reason why `logging.exception(e)` seems to fail is that it passes the exception `e` up into [`logging.Formatter.format()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L474) where the it arrives as `record.message` variable which still is an `Exception` object.

Then in Line 474 the following happens:

```
s = self._fmt % record.__dict__
```

which is equivalent to the following:

```
s = '%(levelname)s:%(name)s:%(message)s' % {
   'levelname': 'ERROR',
   'name': 'ROOT',
   'message': Exception(u'jörn')
}
```

It turns out this is why if `message` is one of `['jörn', u'jörn', Exception('jörn')]` it works and not if it is `Exception(u'jörn')`:

```
>>> 'foo %s' % 'jörn'
'foo j\xc3\xb6rn'
>>> 'foo %s' % u'jörn'
u'foo j\xf6rn'
>>> 'foo %s' % Exception('jörn')
'foo j\xc3\xb6rn'
>>> 'foo %s' % Exception(u'jörn')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf6' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

As you can see there is an automatic upcasting that happens for unicode strings which is why the following works:

```
>>> logging.error('jörn')
ERROR:root:jörn
>>> logging.error(u'jörn')
ERROR:root:jörn
```

This transformation into unicode fails when attempting it with an `Exception` object that doesn't properly handle the encoding of its message (which sadly seems to be the case in a lot of libraries).

The `logging.exception(msg)` call seems to properly use the `repr()` for formatting the exception for logging and prefixes it with your `msg`. So if you don't make the mistake and pass the exception to `logging.exception` it will correctly log it.

#### So long story short:

Don't use `logging.exception(e)` but `logging.exception('exception occurred')`. It will automagically and correctly append the formatted exception to your log. If you really want to use the exception's message without assuming some encoding, the safest you can do is `logging.exception(repr(e))`.

Answer (score 3):

It's not the logging that fails to deal with unicode, it's the Exception.__str__ method which does not support unicode strings as exception arguments. When you invoke `logging.exception(e)` it will do something like `logging.exception(str(e))` which in turn does something like `str(self.args)` on the exception instance. That's where the error comes from, your self.args is a unicode string which cannot be encoded in ascii.
You have two options, either do `logging.exception(unicode(e))` or implement your own exception class that provides a `__str__` method that can deal with unicode objects in self.args.

The reason why your first test passes is that the editor encodes the string into UTF-8 and Python sees a string instance with encoded unicode characters.

Comment: sorry, this doesn't really answer my question: `unicode(Exception('jörn'))` will fail before it even reaches `logging.exception`. I'm asking for a solution that just works with any library and whatever encoding sins their developers embedded in them.

Comment: unicode(Exception('jörn')) failes when decoding the the string if the default encoding is not matching your editor encoding. It was meant to be applied to Exceptions with unicode args: unicode(Exception(u'jörn')). There is no logging facility that supports this, as the problem lies in the Exception class which is not capable of dealing with unicode args.

Comment: You could write a wrapper around logging.exception which inspects Exception.args which checks if there are unicode objects in Exception.args and treats them appropriately.

Answer (score -1):

There's a lot of ways of doing, but most simple is to "patch" logger in order for it to pre-convert any non unicode string so logging won't fail, regardless of source, which is quite useful since you can't control sources like tracebacks, when using something like `logger.error(exc_info=True)`

Patching sounds bad, but fortunately there is a mechanism called a contextfilter that does the job without modifying the code.

**TL;DR: I have built the following code as a package Tested with all Python versions from 2.7 to 3.10. Use it with `pip install ofunctions.logger_utils`**
Usage:

```
from ofunctions.logger_utils import logger_get_logger

logger = logger_get_logger(log_file='somepath')
logger.info('Ûnicode café")
```

**TL;DR end**

Consider the following code which sole purpose is to call function `safe_string_convert()` on a given logged message:

```
class FixPython2Logging(logging.Filter):
    def __init__(self):
        if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
            # pylint: disable=E1003 (bad-super-call)
            super(logging.Filter, self).__init__()
        else:
            super().__init__()

    def filter(self, record):
        # type: (str) -> bool
        # Fix python2 unicodedecodeerrors when non unicode strings are sent to logger
        if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
            record.msg = safe_string_convert(record.msg)
        return True
```

Of course we'd have to design a fool proof (or unicode decode error proof) function that makes sure we'll have a string that can be logged:

```
def safe_string_convert(string):
    """
    Allows to encode strings for hacky UTF-8 logging in python 2.7
    """

    try:
        return string.decode("utf8")
    except Exception:  # noqa
        try:
            return string.decode("unicode-escape")
        except Exception:  # noqa
            try:
                return string.decode("latin1")
            except Exception:  # noqa
                if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
                    # pylint: disable=E0602 (undefined-variable)
                    if isinstance(string, unicode):  # noqa
                        return string
                try:
                    return (
                        b"Cannot convert logged string. Passing it as binary blob: "
                        + bytes(string)
                    )
                except Exception:  # noqa
                    return string
```

Now we can make sure FixPython2Logging filter will get executed by any logger call. Let's just add it as filter to our standard logger class:

```
    log_filter = FixPython2Logging()
    logger = logging.getLogger()

    # Remove earlier handlers if exist
    while _logger.handlers:
        _logger.handlers.pop()

    # Add context filter
    logger.addFilter(log_filter)

    # Try it
    logger.info("Ûnicode café")
```

Here we go ;)
Of course the contextfilter works for your initial logger.exception() question ;)